# GHCi debugger: how to step out of the current expression?

Tags: debugging, haskell, ghci

In your typical imperative debugger, if you end up inside a function you don't care about, you can "step out" of the function (i.e., execute until you end up somewhere else). How do you do that with the GHCi debugger?

Of course, lazy evaluation makes this... a little weird. But I think it's well-defined in my case.

(I'm stepping through some code I wrote, and I've ended up inside Parsec. Well I already know my parser works OK, so I just want to step over the entire parser to the bit where it returns a result — which I *believe* happens "in one go", if you will. How do I skip to that point?)

Comment: Idea: `:force _result`. Alas, that doesn't seem to alter the state of the debugger...

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint and continue?